This room will do me nicely (BE) = This room is just fine (AE)?

do somebody (+ adv./prep.) (especially British English) This room will do me nicely, thank you (= it has everything I need).

[Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary]
What would Americans say to mean This room will do me nicely, thank you?
I would probably say:
This room is just fine, thank you.
Does this sentence sound natural in American English and have the same meaning as This room will do me nicely, thank you?

definitely not the same meaning. "This room will do me nicely" is somewhat of a praise/ positive feedback while "This room is just fine, thank you" shows acceptance of current situation.

There isn't just one translation.  There are lots of ways to say that a room is suitable. I could probably run off 10 or 20 ways that would be natural in British and American English.

The room suits me fine.

"This room is just fine" could mean that it's fine in general, or it's fine for someone specifically (not necessarily the speaker); and it's ambiguous whether it means adequate or significantly better. So it depends both on situation and tone of voice. If someone offers you a room, "This room is just fine" is clear enough. But not in all situations.

"This room will do me nicely" is something an American might say. Yes, meaning is similar to "This room is fine". Either would be fine (!) in America.
I notice you quote some dictionary saying "do somebody +adv/prep". I'd be careful about that. To "do somebody" is a slang term for sex. Like if you say, "I'd really like to do Sally", that means you want to have sex with her. This might be followed by an adverb, like "Alice did Bob roughly". That is, there's a big difference between an object "doing someone", "This room does me nicely", "This country does me fine", and a person doing another person!

To 'do somebody' in the UK can mean to perform a comedic impression of that person.

@MichaelHarvey Good points. That's true in the US also. Which is meant is usually obvious from context. If not ... might be a basis for a joke there.
